# Why does the Ruby ternary operator not allow extending and similar?

Tags: ruby, module, ternary-operator

I have two bits of code that, as far as I understand Ruby, should function identically. Both would sit within the same initialize method:

```
class TicTacToePlayer
  def initialize(player_type = { human: true })
    # Here
  end
end
```

The first code is a standard if/else statement:

```
if player_type[:human]
  extend Human
else
  extend Joshua
end
```

The second is just the above as a ternary operator:

```
player_type[:human] ? extend Human : extend Joshua
```

...

I would expect both to function identically, but whereas the first operates smoothly, the second returns the following error:

> syntax error, unexpected tCONSTANT, expecting keyword_do or '{' or '('
>   ...yer_type[:human] ? extend Human : extend Joshua # ternary op...

Why the difference?

Answer (score 1):

Use parentheses for the function calls

```
player_type[:human] ? extend(Human) : extend(Joshua)
```

Answer (score 1):

As an alternative to using parentheses like @mtm's answer, you can also write it like this:

```
extend player_type[:human] ? Human : Joshua
```